# Kiosk app for iPad that allows using a client side certificate

Tags: ipad, certificate, web-app, client

My web application is demanding a client side certificate to be installed.

When opening the web app from a browser on my iPad, I'm prompted to allow using the certificate and all works well.

Do you know any kiosk app that will give the same functionality? I've tried several with no success, getting 403 error immediately.

Comment: Take a look at [iCab](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/icab-mobile-web-browser/id308111628?mt=8).

Comment: Why not make your own? Create configuration profile to install the certs and use single app mode.

Comment: develop my own app just to display my web page sounds like an overkill

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible by any browser besides `Safari` due to keychain access.

The only solution would be then to develop your own app.